# Laravel 5.1 using phpstorm code completion issue

Tags: laravel, autocomplete, phpstorm

this question may have been asked, but i could not find it so far.

i'm new to laravel (5.1) and phpstorm (v9) and trying a simple controller with a view and route.

I noticed that while typing the code for example:

```
View::make('someView');
```

if i **ignore** the autocomplete (intellisense) and complete the code.
i get a "NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php" error.

But if i apply the suggested autocomplete for example:

Illuminate\Support\Facades\View

it works fine.

May be i've missed some configurations on Laravel or phpstorm or both, may be this issue is in only phpstorm v9. Either ways it sometimes give me a headache, specially as i just started learning.

Btw, even if i've

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;
```

for ever function that i write i still have to apply the autocomplete suggestion.

else i get the same **View not found** error.

Please let me know if there is a way to fix this.

Thanx

Answer (score 1):

Install [barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper) package and follow instructions. It will create helper files that will improve you IDE autocomplete for Laravel project.